# Startup App On Phone Boot

Tags: settings

I need to startup a app Automatic when the phone boots to run a background service on dedicated device (the phone will run only that app for GPS Tracking it will be installed in a vehicel).

By design i did not found such option on windows phone.

Is there any possible way to do that, I have full rights, its my own phone.

Comment: This is not possible on a windows phone.

Answer (score 3):

If the app you want to run in the background, supports background operations, it will be running in the background always unless you stop its background activity from within settings. For example, take a look at WhatsApp, it is always running in the background and lets you receive messages from users. Even if you restart your phone it gets started on it's own in the background.

Specifically there is no option to start an app, when phone boots up, as in windows startup. The app starts itself if it has a registered background activity.